# Usage of colon for further details

Tags: punctuation

> There was still a problem: how to keep the calendar right in the future, year after year.

In this sentence, I have a question of the usage of colon. I found that we need to add a sentence for further detail while using colon.
So I wanted to know whether it needs to rephrase like this.

> There was still a problem: it was how to keep the calendar right in the future, year after year.

Answer (score 1):

As it is used in punctuation, the colon implies that you are going to make a point -- as you say, usually with further details that relate to the first part of the sentence.  [General rules on using the colon](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/colons.asp)

When linking two independent sentences together, as you do in the second example, you should instead use a *semicolon* and not a full colon (unless the second sentence is part of a quote) -- however this is not a definite "rule" but simply a guideline.  So in some cases a colon is fine.

That being said, your sentence is awkward and would be better rephrased to use a simple comma and conjunction:

> There was still a problem, which was how to keep the calendar right in the future, year after year.